# How do you store and manipulate retrieved information from an RSS Feed in Java?

Tags: java, rss, linked-list, saxparser

Well I've run into another problem with RSSParsing.
Here's what I've done so far.
I've successfully accessed the data from the RSSFeed I want.
I've stored the information within it without a problem (to the best of my knowledge) to an Item class object. This class takes in Title, Description, Link, Publication Date.

```
public class Item {

private String link;
private String title;
private String pubDate;
private String description;

// Default Constructor 

public Item()
{
    link = new String();
    title = new String();
    pubDate = new String();
    description = new String();

}

// Parameterized Constructor
public Item(String iTitle, String iDescription, String iLink, String iPubDate)
{
    link = iLink;
    title = iTitle;
    pubDate = iPubDate;
    description = iDescription;
}

public void setDate(String newPubDate)
{
    pubDate = newPubDate;
}

public void setLink(String newLink)
{
    link = newLink;
}

public void setTitle(String newTitle)
{
    title = newTitle;
}

public void setDescription(String newDescription)
{
    description = newDescription;
}

public String getDate()
{
    return pubDate;
}

public String getLink()
{
    return link;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Title: " + title + "\n" + "Publication Date: " + pubDate + "\n" + "Description: " + description + "\n" + "Link: " + link;
}
```

The following is my RSSParser handler class

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import lists.LinkedUnorderedList;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RSSParser extends DefaultHandler{

int itemCount = 0;

boolean item = false;
boolean link = false;
boolean title = false;
boolean pubDate = false;
boolean description = false; 

Item theItem = new Item();
String itemPubDate = new String();


LinkedUnorderedList<Item> theUnorderedList = new LinkedUnorderedList();


public void startDocument()
{
    System.out.println("Starts Parsing the Document.....\n");

}


public void endDocument()
{
    System.out.println(theUnorderedList + "\n\n" + itemCount);
    System.out.println("\nEnds parsing Document...");

}


public void startElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
{

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
    {
        theUnorderedList.addToRear(theItem);
        theItem = new Item();
        itemCount++;
    }
    else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link") )
    {
        link = true;
    }
    else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title") )
    {
        title = true;
    }
    else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate") )
    {
        pubDate = true;
    }
    else if ( qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description") )
    {
        description= true;
    }

}




public void endElement(String nameSpaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
{
    System.out.print("End Element: " + qName );
}



public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
{

    if ( title )
    {
        //System.out.println("Title: "  + new String( ch, start, length ) );
        theItem.setTitle( new String( ch, start, length ) );
        title = false;
    }

    else if ( link )
    {
        //System.out.println("Link: "  + new String( ch, start, length ) );
        theItem.setLink( new String( ch, start, length ) );
        link = false;
    }

    else if ( description )
    {
        //System.out.println("Description: "  + new String( ch, start, length ) );
        theItem.setDescription( new String( ch, start, length ) );
        description = false;
    }

    else if ( pubDate )
    {
        itemPubDate = new String( ch, start, length );

        //System.out.println("PubDate: "  + itemPubDate  + "\nItemCount: " + itemCount + "\n\n");
        theItem.setDate( new String( ch, start, length ) );
        pubDate = false;
    }

} // ends characters Method
```

Lastly is my Application class

```
//import java.net.URL;
//import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
//import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory;


public class Project4 {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, SAXException
{

    XMLReader read = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

    RSSParser parser= new RSSParser();

    read.setContentHandler(parser);

    read.parse("http://feeds.ign.com/ign/games-articles");



} // Ends main
```

}

This works so far. The commented coded printed out what I wanted, which was to print the list of items I've stored in the linked list.
 My main goal is to put all these items in an UnorderedLinkedList which i've done correctly. But my question is how do I give the user access to this list in the application class? For example I want to be able to present the user with options on removing an item from the list. I know the methods for the linked list and how to create a GUI but to be clear, I don't know how access this list from the application class. Or am I creating the LinkedList in the wrong place?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the RSSParser to be a variable in your Project4 class instead and provide methods to access it. Your static main method should instantiate an instance of Project4 and create a new RSSParser(). Use that instance to parse the feed and create a getter method to gain access to it from your GUI.

For example, something like this:

```
public class Project4 {

  private parser RSSParser;

  public RSSParser getParser() {
     return parser
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, SAXException {

     Project4 p = new Project4();
     XMLReader read = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
     p.parser= new RSSParser();
     read.setContentHandler(p.parser);
     read.parse("http://feeds.ign.com/ign/games-articles");

     /// loop here and connect up your GUI

  }
```

}

On a side note, you might want to take a look at the ROME project for parsing RSS feeds.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! SO MUCH!!! Been trying to finish this for a couple of days now. And yes I've looked into using ROME but I can't understand it (don't laugh). Will definitely look into it a little more but my main concern was to be able to handle this project with the default libraries of Java. (SAX or DOM ).